# Timestamp issue into Cassadnra table

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

I am inserting value in timestamp but getting issue like below.

```
insert INTO isbn_seller_det (isd_id, added_date_on ,isbn_no) VALUES ( uuid(),'2014-09-05','9999999999');
```

After insert when I am checking into cassandra table

```
nandan@cqlsh:crawl_dev> SELECT * FROM  isbn_seller_det;

 isd_id                               | added_date_on            | bad_cmt | good_cmt | isbn_no    | our_rate | overall_per | seller_id | tot_com
--------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------
 2dd202ca-2b53-446b-8184-0211bab2a9d7 | 2014-09-05 00:00:00+0000 |    null |     null | 9999999999 |     null |        null |      null |    null
```

I am getting exact right. But when I am trying to check this record in PHP API, My added_date_on column reflect some interger value as 1125927240.

So can you please tell me what is wrong with this.  Which type of conversion is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the method [toDateTime()](https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/class.Timestamp/#method-toDateTime) ?

Comment: Yes , but this method is not accepting.. Please suggest me something.. Is there any need for any configuration from cassandra side... then also guide me.

Comment: Please share the column family definition; you can get it with the command _DESCRIBE TABLE <keyspace>.isbn_seller_det;_ from cqlsh

Comment: Below is the column family definition.

CREATE TABLE crawl_dev.isbn_seller_det (
    isd_id uuid,
    added_date_on timestamp,
    bad_cmt int,
    good_cmt int,
    isbn_no text,
    our_rate text,
    overall_per int,
    seller_id uuid,
    tot_com int,
    PRIMARY KEY (isd_id, added_date_on)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (added_date_on ASC)
CREATE INDEX isbn_seller_det_added_date_on_idx ON crawl_dev.isbn_seller_det (added_date_on);